# How to create ext4 image with exact size for specified files

Tags: bash, dd

I have to prepare an ext4 image that will contain content of a provided directory. The size of image should be just above the required space.

My procedure was to check the directory content's size, than use `dd` to create an empty image with some extra space and finally create ext4 filesystem using `mkfs.ext4' with the`-d` flag to provide files to write to it.

```sh
# check size in kB (in my case it's 27700)
size=$( du -sk ./trg | awk '{print $1 }')
# add extra 1000kB
extra="1000"
# create empty file with dd
dd if=/dev/zero of=out.dd seek=$size bs=1024 count=$extra
# create filesystem
mkfs.ext4 -F out.dd -d ./trg
```

I expected that the size of image will be `27700+1000` so everything should fit into `28700kB`, but the output image is much smaller than expected:

```sh
$ du -sk ./*
26340   ./out.dd
4   ./test.sh
27700   ./trg
```

What am I missing? where is this space lost?

Comment: Does `ls -l` give you the size you expect?

Comment: `ls -l' will not work on directory - It will return the `4k` for the directory itself not it's content.

Comment: I'm not talking about the directory but the image file. The size du gives is not always the same as the one ls does (but Léa has already hinted at that).

Comment: oh, sorry. But still size returned by `ls -l` is same as one from `du -sk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`du -sk` prints disk usage in kilobytes. Disk usage is not actual file size but the place it takes on disk. It means that sparse bytes (blanks) may take less space on disk than their amount.

If you want `du` to print actual data size rather than disk usage:

Use the `--apparent-size` option:

> **--apparent-size**
>
> print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like

Comment: using `--apparent-size` gives me even smaller size, so it still won't fit on created image.
`$ du -sk --apparent-size ./*` `27693 ./trg`
```